# What is "efficiency" in this machine architecture infographic?

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture, power-architecture

Raptor Engineering released this infographic (below) comparing POWER8 to other processor architectures. ([source](https://raptorengineeringinc.com/TALOS/power_advantages.php), [context](https://raptorengineeringinc.com/TALOS/prerelease.php))

In the context of machine architectures, what does "efficiency" refer to?

[image: High level comparison of machine architectures]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be answered by the creator of the image, Raptor Engineering. Besides, it's not specifically about programming so may be better off on a sister site.

Comment: Efficiency could be *any* number of things. Thermal efficiency, transfer efficiency, etc.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I was hoping someone more familiar with CPUs would be able to infer something from the context (see links) - but maybe it is too vague and/or specific - is there a hardware stack?

Comment: Not sure if there's a hardware stack, but there is [Super User](http://superuser.com/about) which deals with "Questions about general computing hardware and software". Maybe check it's on-topic there before asking though.

Comment: Probably 1/energy per computation.  (i.e. performance / power).  They show ARM as having a perfect score for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from Raptor (emphasis added):

> That metric refers to **power efficiency and scalability**; specifically as
>   [I|F]LOPS are reduced how well the chip's power consumption also scales
>   down.  x86 and ARM are the clear winners here due to ARM's relatively
>   simplistic design and Intel's aggressive lowering of process node size.